# How to add/remove pages in Devex wizard control using c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms

My current implementation is as follows:
Initially Wizard control adds two pages: 1. Option Selection and 2. Option Summary.

At run time depending on the option selection, I have to show either one more option page or option summary page.

So I am adding Option Selection page on click of Next button and removing Option Selection page from wizard control on click of Back button.

Question:When I navigate from one page to another on click of Back button in the wizard, the Summary page appears for a fraction of second and then is replaced by the correct page (Option Selection Page).

I have noticed when I remove any page from wizard pages list the direction changes from Backward to Forward.

Kindly help me on this.